# Why does height:auto size to the child content and display:inline size to the grandparent?

Tags: html, css

If a parent element has a height of auto, a child element with a height of 100% will size to the child content.

**Example:**

```css
html, body{  height:100%;  padding:0;  margin:0;}
.grandParent{
  background-color:red;  
  height:100%;
}

.parent{
  background-color:blue;
  height:auto;
}

.child{
  background-color:green;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandParent">  
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if you set the parent element to display:inline, a child element with a height of 100% it will size to 100% of the grandparent.

**Example:**

```css
html, body{  height:100%;  padding:0;  margin:0;}

.grandParent{
  background-color:red;  
  height:100%;
}

.parent{
  background-color:blue;
  display:inline;
}

.child{
  background-color:green;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandParent">  
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does height:auto size to the child content and display:inline size to the grandparent?

Comment: I think inline elements get ignored completely when setting percentage heights so the child will look to see what the next block level parent element is and then set it's height to whatever that is

Answer (score 1):

The `height: auto` gives the div the height that contents have. So if you have a line of code it will have `20px` height for example but if you have two lines the height will be double of that.

In the `height` `auto` the browser calculates the height.